# Random character from a short string - can the randomness be influenced?

Tags: math, random, probability

If I have a very short string, say (JavaScript):

```
var = "abcd";
```

and I want to get a random character from it, I could use:

```
var random_char = str.charAt( Math.floor(Math.random() * str.length) );
```

Now `Math.floor(Math.random() * str.length)` returns a random number in the range `[0..3]`.

Can the perceived randomness of the returned character be increased by multiplying the string, i.e. by effectively increasing the range of the random numbers?

```
var = "abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That won't change anything. `Math.random()` returns a pseudo-random value between in `[0..1)`. Assuming the random number generator is of good quality, it won't make a difference whether you map its range to `abc` or to `abcabcabc`.

If `Math.random()` *returned* random numbers of very low quality (i.e. a human being could spot the logic behind them just by looking at the number sequence), your strategy would indeed increase the perceived 'randomness'. But that's not relevant since JavaScript runtimes are typically not written by monkeys.

Comment: Yeah, makes absolute sense. Stupid question now that I think about it. Writing a quick reality check in the browser took less time than writing up that question. oO

Answer (score 3):

I would say no. It still is a 25% probability for getting a, b, c or d.

Comment: Really?  How does the pigeonhole principle apply?  There aren't more pigeons than holes here.

Answer (score 3):

No, it cannot.  Worse yet, you will get an error 12.5% of the time, as `Math.round` will round values from 3.5 to 3.999999 up to 4.